# Can‘t run npm start, it shows npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

When I run `npm start` it shows below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui/webpack.config.js:15:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:84:40)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bim-ui@1.0.0 dev: `set NODE_ENV=development &&  webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bim-ui@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-03-18T15_53_56_588Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bim-ui@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bim-ui@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-03-18T15_53_56_622Z-debug.log
```

and the debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~prestart: bim-ui@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~start: bim-ui@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui
10 silly lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle bim-ui@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: bim-ui@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid bim-ui@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/bim-ui
16 verbose Darwin 20.3.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error bim-ui@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bim-ui@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Tried almost everything include deleting whole node.js and uninstalling all the packages, still doesn't work.

Comment: @rory quote formatting errors blows away the line breaks, prefer code blocks

Comment: add details - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`

Comment: could you share the package.json?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can preserve the line breaks in quote blocks by putting double spaces at the end of the line, but you're right here that it looks better in the code block without the  word wrapping